# How to fix "The method 'CustomTimerPainter' isn't defined" error in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, countdowntimer, custom-painter

I'm encountering the following error in my Flutter countdown timer implementation:

```
 59:48: Error: The method 'CustomTimerPainter' isn't defined for the class '_CountDownTimerState'.
 - '_CountDownTimerState' is from 'package:braintrinig/pages/Countdown_timer.dart' ('lib/pages/Countdown_timer.dart'). Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'CustomTimerPainter'.
                    painter: CustomTimerPainter(
```

**Relevant code:**

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

class CountDownTimer extends StatefulWidget {
  // ...
}

class _CountDownTimerState extends State<CountDownTimer> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  // ... 

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // ... 

            CustomPaint(
              painter: CustomTimerPainter( 
                 animation: controller,
                 backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                 color: themeData.indicatorColor,
              ),
            ),

    // ... 
  }
}
```

**Things I've tried:**

- Checked my imports (I don't see where `CustomTimerPainter` might be defined).
- Verified that the file with the `CustomTimerPainter` class is accessible and correctly imported.

**Question:**
Can you help me determine why I'm getting this error and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It checked that "CustomTimerPainter" is from circular_countdown_timer library.
After you add this library, the problem you mentioned will be resolved.

I pasted your code to my project and install "circular_countdown_timer", I didn't see any error right now.

[circular_countdown_timer pub.dev](https://pub.dev/packages/circular_countdown_timer/install)

[image]

1. Add circular_countdown_timer in your pubspec.yaml => get => update.

```dart
dependencies:
  circular_countdown_timer: ^0.2.2
```

2. Import this library into your dart file

```dart
import 'package:circular_countdown_timer/custom_timer_painter.dart';
```

Answer (score 2):

The CustomeTimerPainter is a custom widget that someone has already written in your taken example,

You may please check those examples, or you can use the sample below.

```
class CustomTimerPainter extends CustomPainter {
  CustomTimerPainter({
    this.animation,
    this.backgroundColor,
    this.color,
  }) : super(repaint: animation);

  final Animation<double> animation;
  final Color backgroundColor, color;

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Paint paint = Paint()
      ..color = backgroundColor
      ..strokeWidth = 10.0
      ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.butt
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke;

    canvas.drawCircle(size.center(Offset.zero), size.width / 2.0, paint);
    paint.color = color;
    double progress = (1.0 - animation.value) * 2 * math.pi;
    canvas.drawArc(Offset.zero & size, math.pi * 1.5, -progress, false, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomTimerPainter old) {
    return animation.value != old.animation.value ||
        color != old.color ||
        backgroundColor != old.backgroundColor;
  }
}
```